# Starting cumsum of a rasterfile from value of another rast file in terra

Tags: raster, r, terra

I have one raster and one raster stack. The single raster layer represent day of year when I need to start cumulative sum of the raster stack.

```
Rstart<-rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
Rstart[]<-1:100

RcumSum<-rast(nrow=10,ncol=1000)
RcumSum[]<-1
```

I know how to do it converting stack raster to matrix and vector then do the computation through a loop

```
Rstart<-as.vector(Rstart)
RcumSum<-as.matrix(RcumSum)
Fsstop=15
Result<-vector(length = nrow(RcumSum))
for (i in 1:nrow(RcumSum)){
  Res<-RcumSum[i,]
  
  accum.units <- cumsum(RcumSum[Rstart[i]:length(RcumSum)])
  dayBreak <- which(accum.units>=Fsstop)[1]+Rstart[i]
  
  Result[i]<- dayBreak
}
```

Buit any guess to do it directly from the raster file, using app or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question.

Rstart: single raster with DOY when cumsum starts
RcumSum: multilayer raster with values to sum

Is that right?

If so, and using app function, it could be something like this (the multilayer raster is set to 1 for better understand the output):

```
library(terra)

Rstart<-rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(Rstart)<-1:100

RcumSum<-rast(nrow=10,ncol=10, nlyrs=365)
for (i in 1:365){
  values(RcumSum)[,i] = 1
}

cumsumr = function(x){
  start = x[1]
  end = length(x)
  if(!is.na(start)){
    if((start+1)==end){
      continue
    }else{
      x[(start+1):end] = cumsum(x[(start+1):end])
    }
  }
  return(x[2:end])
}

result = app(c(Rstart,RcumSum),cumsumr)
```

First day, no cumsum `plot(result[[1]])`:
[image]

DOY 50 (`plot(result[[50]])`):
[image]

Last day of the year (`plot(result[[365]])`):
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it exactly what i was looking for !